# Sum of random error in regression

Tags: statistics, self-learning, regression

> If you know that $\sum_{i=1}^n e_i=0$.What can you say about
>   $\sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_i=0$? Where $e_i=Y_i-\hat{Y_i}$ and
>   $\epsilon_i=Y_i-E[Y_i]$.

I know that $$Y_i=B_0+B_1X_i+\epsilon_i$$
and $$E[Y_i]=B_0+B_1X_i$$
then I try
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_i=\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-E[\hat{Y_i}+e_i])=\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-E[\hat{Y_i}]-E[e_i])=\sum_{i=1}^nY_i-B_0-B_1X_i-e_i$$
since that $$E[\hat{Y_i}]=E[\hat{B_0}+\hat{B_1}X_i+\epsilon_i]=B_0+B_1X_i$$
thus
$$\sum_{i=1}^nY_i-B_0-B_1X_i-e_i=\sum_{i=1}^n(B_0+B_1X_i+\epsilon_i-B_0-B_1X_i-e_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_i-e_i$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_i-e_i=0\Leftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_i=\sum_{i=1}^ne_i\Leftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_i=0$$
can anyone help?

Comment: I have not gone through the whole calculation but you do have the latter of this expression..$$\mathrm{E}[Y_i] = B_0 + B_1\mathrm{E}[X_i]\neq B_0 + B_1X_i$$

Comment: @Chinny84 : If $X_i$ is constant (i.e. not random) the what was written was correct.  Moreover, for practical purposes one often treats $X_i$ as constant because one is in effect estimating conditional expected values given $X_i$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @michealhardy I didn't think of that scenario. I will retract my comment until further information. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**begin quote**

> If you know that $\sum_{i=1}^n e_i=0$, show that
>   $\sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_i=0$ where $e_i=Y_i-\hat{Y_i}$ and
>   $\epsilon_i=Y_i-E[Y_i]$.

I know that $$Y_i=B_0+B_1X_i+\epsilon_i$$
and $$E[Y_i]=B_0+B_1X_i$$

**end quote**

Some assumptions are omitted here.  Usually one says something like $Y_i = B_0+ B_1 X_i + \varepsilon_i$ where $B_0$, $B_1$, and $X_i$ are not random (or else that $X_i$ are treated as if they were not random because we want to think of distributions as conditional distributions given $X_i$) and $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are observed and one is to estimate $B_0$ and $B_1$, and all this is for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

But there are also assumptions about the distributions of $\varepsilon_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.  To make this answer as broadly applicable as it can reasonably be, we won't assume $\varepsilon_i$ are independent, but only that they are uncorrelated, and we won't assume they are identically distributed, but only that they all have expected value $0$ and variance $\sigma^2<\infty$.

The least-squares estimates of $B_0$ and $B_1$ are $\hat B_0$ and $\hat B_1$ and the fitted values are $\hat Y_i = \hat B_0 + \hat B_1 X_i$, and

> the $i$th **error** is $\varepsilon_i$, and
>
> the $i$th **residual** is $e_i = Y_i - \hat Y_i$ (often called $\hat\varepsilon_i$).

(The residual is an observable estimate of the unobservable error.)

It can be shown to follow from the nature of least-squares estimates that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n e_i = 0 \quad\text{and} \quad \sum_{i=1}^n e_i X_i = 0.
$$

However, you **cannot** prove under the assumptions above that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \varepsilon_i = 0$.
Notice that
$$
\operatorname{var}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n \varepsilon_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{var} (\varepsilon_i) = \sigma^2+\cdots+\sigma^2 = n\sigma^2>0.
$$
(There are no covariance terms because the $\varepsilon_i$ are uncorrelated.)

It cannot always be $0$ if its variance is positive.

Comment: I think your reasoning is totally right, indeed the question asks: What can you say about $\sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_i=0$?